# Using async/await inside a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, material-ui, react-functional-component

I'm just beginning to use React for a project, and am really struggling with incorporating async/await functionality into one of my components.

I have an asynchronous function called `fetchKey` that goes and gets an access key from an API I am serving via AWS API Gateway:

```
const fetchKey = async authProps => {
  try {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: authProps.idToken // using Cognito authorizer
    };

    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://MY_ENDPOINT.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/",
      API_GATEWAY_POST_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE,
      {
        headers: headers
      }
    );
      return response.data.access_token;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Axios request failed! : ${e}`);
    return e;
  }
};
```

I am using React's Material UI theme, and waned to make use of one of its Dashboard templates. Unfortunately, the Dashboard template uses a functional stateless component:

```
const Dashboard = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const token = fetchKey(props.auth);
  console.log(token);

  return (
  ... rest of the functional component's code
```

The result of my `console.log(token)` is a Promise, which is expected, but the screenshot in my Google Chrome browser is somewhat contradictory - is it pending, or is it resolved?
[image]

Second, if I try instead `token.then((data, error)=> console.log(data, error))`, I get `undefined` for both variables. This seems to indicate to me that the function has not yet completed, and therefore has not resolved any values for `data` or `error`. Yet, if I try to place a

```
const Dashboard = async props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const token = await fetchKey(props.auth);
```

React complains mightily:

```
> react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are
> not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to
> render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>     in Dashboard (at App.js:89)
>     in Route (at App.js:86)
>     in Switch (at App.js:80)
>     in div (at App.js:78)
>     in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>     in BrowserRouter (at App.js:77)
>     in div (at App.js:76)
>     in ThemeProvider (at App.js:75)
```

Now, I'll be the first to state I don't have enough experience to understand what is going on with this error message. If this was a traditional React class component, I'd use the `this.setState` method to set some state, and then go on my merry way. However, I don't have that option in this functional component.

How do I incorporate async/await logic into my functional React component?

**Edit:** So I will just say I'm an idiot. The actual response object that is returned is not `response.data.access_token`. It was `response.data.Item.access_token`. Doh! That's why the result was being returned as undefined, even though the actual promise was resolved.

Comment: `is it pending, or is it resolved` it's resolved when you inspected it in the console - that doesn't mean it was resolved when you logged it ... the console "lies" :p

Comment: `token.then((data, error)` ... the callback function to `.then` (for an actual Promise/A+ spec Promise) will only ever have a single argument - other "Promise like" promises (e.g. jQuery) break this spec - if `data` is `undefined` that implies that `response.data.access_token` is `undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Async await in react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936559/using-async-await-in-react-component)

Comment: Can you check if you are getting a proper response from the axios call? And also if `return response.data.access_token;` is not undefined?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You will have to make sure two things

- `useEffect` is similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, so if you use `setState` here then you need to restrict the code execution at some point when used as `componentDidUpdate` as shown below:

```js
function Dashboard() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // React advises to declare the async function directly inside useEffect
    async function getToken() {
      const headers = {
        Authorization: authProps.idToken // using Cognito authorizer
      };
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://MY_ENDPOINT.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/",
        API_GATEWAY_POST_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE,
        { headers }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setToken(data.access_token);
    };

    // You need to restrict it at some point
    // This is just dummy code and should be replaced by actual
    if (!token) {
        getToken();
    }
  }, []);

  return <>/*Rendering code*/</>;
}
```

Comment: `getToken = async () => {` Helped me Thank you

Comment: Two problems to watch out for: 1) The `useEffect` is missing `token` and `getToken` as dependencies. 2) Since `getToken` is async, it could call `setToken` after the component is unmounted.

Comment: 1) No it's not missing any dependencies as it just needs to be called once, which can only be done with just `[]`
2) Yes, thats the valid scenario which can be handled with a check of screen being visible or not.

Comment: If it's only called once, then why bother restricting it with `if (!token)`? If `token` changes, it would trigger the side-effect again which is why you guard against that but it also means `token` _really is_ a dependency of the side-effect.

Comment: @MarcDingena You are right, we don't need `!token` if we have no dependency added. Restriction would be required when you use `useEffect` as `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: As everyone is talking about token, to avoid doing this async check every time, better use Global State with Redux or `React.useContext` to check asynchronously at the very beginning.

Comment: That's just ugly unfortunately. Callback hell all over again.

Answer (score 111):

With React Hooks, you can now achieve the same thing as Class component in functional component now.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dashboard = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
     async function getToken() {
         const token = await fetchKey(props.auth);
         setToken(token);
     }
     getToken();
  }, [])


  return (
  ... rest of the functional component's code
  // Remember to handle the first render when token is null
```

Also take a look at this: [Using Async await in react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936559/using-async-await-in-react-component)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the previous will require useEffect to be async. The simplest way to encapsulate the asynchronous code is inside a async IIFE.

Answer (score 3):

Component might unmount or re-render with different `props.auth` before `fetchKey` is resolved:

```
const Dashboard = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  
  const unmountedRef = useRef(false);
  useEffect(()=>()=>(unmountedRef.current = true), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const effectStale = false; // Don't forget ; on the line before self-invoking functions
    (async function() {
      const response = await fetchKey(props.auth);

      /* Component has been unmounted. Stop to avoid
         "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component." */
      if(unmountedRef.current) return;

        /* Component has re-rendered with different someId value
         Stop to avoid updating state with stale response */
      if(effectStale) return;

      if(response instanceof Error)
        setError(response)
      else
        setToken(response);
    })();
    return ()=>(effectStale = true);
  }, [props.auth]);

  if( error )
    return <>Error fetching token...{error.toString()}</>
  if( ! token )
    return <>Fetching token...</>

  return //... rest of the functional component's code
```

An alternative is using [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) and [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html):

```
// render Dashboard with <DashboardSuspend>

const Dashboard = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const [token, idToken] = props.tokenRef.current || [];

  // Fetch token on first render or when props.auth.idToken has changed
  if(token === void 0 || idToken !== props.auth.idToken){
    /* The thrown promise will be caught by <React.Suspense> which will render
       it's fallback until the promise is resolved, then it will attempt
       to render the Dashboard again */
    throw (async()=>{
      const initRef = props.tokenRef.current;
      const response = await fetchKey(props.auth);
      /* Stop if tokenRef has been updated by another <Dashboard> render,
         example with props.auth changed causing a re-render of 
         <DashboardSuspend> and the first request is slower than the second */
      if(initRef !== props.tokenRef.current) return;
      props.tokenRef.current = [response, props.auth.idToken];
    })()
  }

  if(props.tokenRef.current instanceof Error){
    /* await fetchKey() resolved to an Error, throwing it will be caught by 
       <ErrorBoundary> which will render it's fallback */ 
    throw props.tokenRef.current
  }

  return //... rest of the functional component's code
}

const DashboardSuspend = props => {

  /* The tokenRef.current will reset to void 0 each time this component is
     mounted/re-mounted. To keep the value move useRef higher up in the 
     hierarchy and pass it down with props or useContext. An alternative
     is using an external storage object such as Redux. */
  const tokenRef = useRef();

  const errorFallback = (error, handleRetry)=>{
    const onRetry = ()=>{
      // Clear tokenRef otherwise <Dashboard> will throw same error again
      tokenRef.current = void 0;
      handleRetry();
    }
    return <>
      Error fetching token...{error.toString()}
      <Button onClick={onRetry}>Retry</Button>
    </>
  }

  const suspenseFallback = <>Fetching token...</>

  return <ErrorBoundary fallback={errorFallback}>
    <React.Suspense fallback={suspenseFallback}>
      <Dashboard {...props} tokenRef={tokenRef} />
    </React.Suspense>
  </ErrorBoundary>
}

// Original ErrorBoundary class: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null };
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
        return { error };
    }
    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
        // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
        console.log(error, errorInfo);
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            // You can render any custom fallback UI
            const handleRetry = () => this.setState({ error: null });
            return typeof this.props.fallback === 'function' ? this.props.fallback(this.state.error, handleRetry) : this.props.fallback
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const token = fetchKey(props.auth);
```

This returns a promise. To get the data from it, this is one way to do it:

```
let token = null;
fetchKey(props.auth).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
  token = result;
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Let me know if that works.

I recreated a similar example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wood-bbygk

Comment: No, this does not work. As I said, the `result` in `then(result => ...)` is undefined.

Comment: Then you must be something wrong. I recreated a similar example, take a look: https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wood-bbygk

Comment: You were right. I just accepted your answer. I didn't inspect my response object carefully enough.

Comment: In a React Component this doesn't trigger an UI Update by itself (Immutability from FP). You have to change internal state to trigger a re-render