# useEffect runs infinite loop despite no change in dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have Function Component that utilizes hooks. In the **useEffect** hook, I simply want to fetch data from my back end and store the results in state. However, despite adding the data variable as a dependency, useEffect still fires on an infinite loop - **even though the data hasn't changed**. How can I stop useEffect from firing continuously?

I've tried the empty array hack, which DOES stop useEffect from continuously firing, but it's not the desired behavior. If the user saves new data, for example, useEffect should fire again to get updated data - I'm not looking to emulate componentDidMount.

```
const Invoices = () => {
  const [invoiceData, setInvoiceData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateInvoiceData = async () => {
      const results = await api.invoice.findData();
      setInvoiceData(results);
    };
    updateInvoiceData();
  }, [invoiceData]);

  return (
    <Table entries={invoiceData} />
  );
};
```

I expected useEffect to fire after the initial render, and again ONLY when invoiceData changes.

Comment: Have a look at my explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component/57856876#57856876

Comment: Isn't this the same behavior as an empty dependency array?

if (!invoiceData) updateInvoiceData();

Comment: It will keep on getting called if there is some value in `invoiceData`. The second argument in `useEffect` will handle that better and will only execute the code when value in `invoiceData` is changed. But if the value is getting changed every time you are making a call then this won't work.

Comment: I would suggest the move the `updateInvoiceData` logic to separate method and use`useEffect` only for the first time and then whenever new data is saved, call the method again(Do not use `useEffect`)

Comment: @Trevor How did you solve this? I have similar problem. The most voted answer pointed out the problem but offer no solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The way the useEffect dependency array works is by checking for strict (`===`) equivalency between all of the items in the array from the previous render and the new render. Therefore, putting an array into your useEffect dependency array is extremely hairy because array comparison with `===` checks equivalency *by reference* not by contents.

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3];
const bar = foo;
foo === bar; // true

const foo = [1, 2, 3];
const bar = [1, 2, 3];
foo === bar; // false
```

Inside of your effect function, when you do `setInvoiceData(results)` you are updating `invoiceData` to a new array. Even if all the items inside of that new array are exactly the same, the *reference* to the new `invoiceData` array has changed, causing the dependencies of the effect to differ, triggering the function again -- ad infinitum.

One simple solution is to simply remove `invoiceData` from the dependency array. In this way, the useEffect function basically acts similar to componentDidMount in that it will trigger once and only once when the component first renders.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const updateInvoiceData = async () => {
      const results = await api.invoice.findData();
      setInvoiceData(results);
    };
    updateInvoiceData();
  }, []);
```

This pattern is so common (and useful) that it is even mentioned in [the official React Hooks API documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects):

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

Comment: That works when the exhaustive deps is turned off  but when that is required?

Comment: @Ryan `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: that leaves room for bugs, is there not a better solution? I've seen some implement useRefs.

Comment: @Ryan What bugs do you mean? Ultimately it is up to the programmer to understand how useEffect and the dependency array works and utilize them properly. There is no way for eslint or any other static analysis tool to “know” whether you intend a useEffect hook to act like a “componentDidMount” or not and lint accordingly. If you’re worried about dropping too many `eslint-disable` comments, you could write a `useOnMount()` custom hook for yourself which simply wraps the desired behavior (empty deps array, cleanup and eslint comment).

Answer (score 3):

Credit to jered for the great "under the hood" explanation; I also found Milind's suggestion to separate out the update method from useEffect to be particularly fruitful.
My solution, truncated for brevity, is as follows -

```
const Invoices = () => {
  const [invoiceData, setInvoiceData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {    
    updateInvoiceData();
  }, []);

  // Extracting this method made it accessible for context/prop-drilling
  const updateInvoiceData = async () => {
    const results = await api.invoice.findData();
    setInvoiceData(results);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponentThatUpdatesData handleUpdateState={updateInvoiceData} />
      <Table entries={invoiceData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening, is that when you update the `invoiceData`, that technically changes the state of `invoiceData`, which you have watched by the `useEffect` hook, which causes the hook to run again, which updates `invoiceData`. If you want `useEffect` to run on mount, which I suspect, then pass an empty array to the second parameter of `useEffect`, which simulates `componentDidMount` in class components. Then, you'll be able to update the local UI state with your useState hook.

Comment: +1. This would be the good example when we can "fake" the deps with `[]` as updating `invoiceData` would trigger re-render, which runs effect, then sets `invoiceData` agains, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Jared's answer.
But for some scenarios where you really want to not have reference comparison, then useDeepCompareEffect from react-use library is really good
https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/HEAD/docs/useDeepCompareEffect.md