# async/await in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I'm doing something like the following

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847874/433570)

```
 const LowerCard = (props) => {

   let { review_meta, step } = props
   const [component, setComponent] = useState('');
   const {state, editDispatch} = useContext(ReviewMetaEditCardDispatch);

   useEffect(() => {

     // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847874/433570

     const setDynamicComponent = async () => {
       let DynamicComponent
       switch(state.step) {
       case 'title':
         DynamicComponent = await import('review/react/components/review-meta-edit-card/step/title')
         break
       }

       if (DynamicComponent) {
         setComponent(DynamicComponent.default)
       }
     }

     setDynamicComponent()
   }, []);


   if (!component) {
     return null
   }

   return (
     <View>
       <component/>
     </View>
   )
   }
```

The above code works, but when I remove `[]` at the `useEffect` call, it results in 
`index.js:1 Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function.`

I'm guessing it's complaining you shouldn't call `setComponent` (which is a hook) inside `useEffect`.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: oh, then How do I run the above code for componentDidUpdate equivalent?

Comment: I tried adding [state.step] which is what causes me to change component, but it still generates the same error

Comment: Do you have other conditions inside the effect? when you want to re-run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic component is using hooks and if you call `importedComponent.default` React will throw and error error of using hooks inside of `useEffect`.

Instead, load the component and call `.default` when you render it.

I've also added `state.step` to `useEffect` dependencies array to make sure to re-run the effect if when `state.step` changes as if on initial render state.step is not `title` the component will never render as you provided an empty dependencies array

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // same as before
  // ...
  if (DynamicComponent) {
    setComponent(DynamicComponent);
  }
}, [state.step])

if (!component) {
  return null;
}

return (
  <View>
    <component.default />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: DynamicComponent.default is not calling it but just reading a reference. attaching .default inside useEffect or in render makes no difference

Comment: @Max It actually does make a difference, if you call `DynamicComponent.default` inside `useEffect` React will error as it's returning the result of the default exported component

Comment: @Max https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-leaf-wdk6l remove the commented lines and see the difference, make sure to comment the other ones

Comment: it was indeed because of  `*.default`

Comment: @AsafAviv I tried your example and it indeed works with `setComponent(DynamicComponent)`. However it's still not clear to me why this happens, because here `setComponent(DynamicComponent.default)` we are not calling a function - calling it would be `setComponent(DynamicComponent.default())`. I will do some additional investigation when I have more time

Comment: @Max Yes you're right it doesn't execute the function, i wonder why it does this as well

Answer (score 2):

You should not use async function directly inside useEffect.

here is my solution see if it works

```js
const LowerCard = props => {
  let {review_meta, step} = props;
  const [component, setComponent] = useState('');
  const {state, editDispatch} = useContext(ReviewMetaEditCardDispatch);

  const setDynamicComponent = useCallback(async () => {
    let DynamicComponent;
    switch (state.step) {
      case 'title':
        DynamicComponent = await import('review/react/components/review-meta-edit-card/step/title');
        break;
    }

    if (DynamicComponent) {
      setComponent(DynamicComponent.default);
    }
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847874/433570
    setDynamicComponent();
  }, [setDynamicComponent]);

  if (!component) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <component />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: try `{component}` instead of `<component/>`

Comment: custom component names in JSX should be uppercased