# nextjs: _app.js renders child components before wrapper components (async react context dependent on indexed db browser store)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, indexeddb, react-context

in my `pages/_app.js` i have this:

```js
  if (process.browser) {
    myidb.init().then((result) => {
      console.log('setup complete! Got:', result)

      return (
        <AppLayout>
          <ItemProvider idbstore={result}>
            <Component { ...pageProps} />
          </ItemProvider>
        </AppLayout>
      )
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('could not setup browser db!', error)
      return(
        <h1>Error - we never get here tho, cos setup up always succeeds, but TOO LATE to be useful.</h1>
      )
    })
  }
```

The `ItemProvider` is just a functional HOC, essentially:

```
export const ItemProvider = ({children, idbstore}) => {
  // ... setup stuff
  return (<ItemContext.Provider value={...}>{children}</ItemContext.Provider>)
}
```

From logging, I see:

- the react context provider  is called immediately, **before `myidb.init()` has a chance to finish opening the indexeddb connection**, so the context has incomplete setup, and subsequent indexeddb calls fail once the app is running.
- the `<ItemProvider>` is **never called again** by nextjs, so has no chance to recover. Only the targeted page component rebuilds.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the promise.then() not work as expected in _app.js and how can i wait for an indexed db to be setup *before* _app.js renders my page components?

Comment: Is it not possible to `async await` this instead?

Comment: @NicholasG04 yeah i probably should. Will do that next and see if it uncovers anything.

Comment: @NicholasG04 actually that helped fix my problem. Your async/await prompt caused me to look up [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component) and I ended up cleaning out _app.js completely and letting <ItemProvider> manage indexeddb setup via `useEffect` hooks. THANKS!!! :D

Comment: That is for sure a better solution, glad I could help in some way :)