# Javascript difficulty consuming promise values even after using await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing an async function to query a DynamoDB table using the AWS SDK:

```
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    var params = { Key: { chart_name: "cambridge_rent" }, TableName: "charts" };
    const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
    return data.Item.values;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Failure", err.message);
  }
}

const result = fetchData();
```

However, I'm having trouble extracting values from `result`, which contains a Promise object:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: Array [ (95) […] ]
```

I'm trying to extract the values from: `<value>: Array [ (95) […] ]`. How do I do so? Is my current approach incorrect?

Comment: You are using `async` in a slightly strange manner-- you should either `await` the `fetchData()` call or you should chain a `.then` on the promise object and do whatever you need with the result in a callback.

Comment: Since the question is in the context of React, you can't await inside the render phase, so take a look at: [Using async/await inside a React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    var params = { Key: { chart_name: "cambridge_rent" }, TableName: "charts" };
    const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
    return data.Item.values;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Failure", err.message);
  }
}

    fetchData().then((resp) => console.log(resp));
```

Comment: great thanks accepting for completeness

Comment: @mmz note that if this is used within a React component's rendering phase, it would fetch each time the component renders, which is inefficient, and an anti-pattern (rendering should be pure) which could lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: @EmileBergeron noted. I'm using it inside a `useEffect` hook would is working for me

Comment: @mmz inside `useEffect` would be fine!

Answer (score 1):

Change `const result = fetchData();` into `const result = await fetchData();`

Comment: Already tried that and getting this error: `Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function (36:15)`. I'm using React and this is outside a component. Doing so inside a component gets me this error: `Unexpected reserved word 'await'`.