# I have a react component that throws a ts error when i use async with React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to create a React functional component DashboardPage that fetches data asynchronously using await, but I'm encountering a TypeScript error. The error message I'm getting is:

```
'Type '({ params }: DashboardPageProps) => Promise<Element>' is not assignable to type 'FC<DashboardPageProps>'. Type 'Promise<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key.'
```

How can I resolve this error and use async/await in my React component correctly?

```
import prismadb from '@/lib/prismadb'

interface DashboardPageProps {
    params: { storeId: string }
}

const DashboardPage: React.FC<DashboardPageProps> = async ({ params }) => {
    const store = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
        where: {
            id: params.storeId
        }
    })
    return <div>Active Store: {store?.name}</div>
}

export default DashboardPage
```

follow up
I am trying to use the async keyword with a React functional component declared as React.FC. but it says this is not allowed because the async keyword makes the component return a Promise, and React components are expected to return JSX elements directly.

thing is I saw similar code on youtube and it worked without errors
it even worked for me but i have these red lines I do not like seeing and the typescript error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await inside a React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component)

Answer (score 0):

Using `React.FC` (or React.FunctionalComponent) is not needed and is [generally not recommended](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components/). I don't have a source at hand that speaks for the entire community but if you check the Next.js documentation for async server-side components, they don't use React.FC and if you check the React documentation for normal functional components, they also won't use it. They [removed React.FC from the Typescript template in create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) for this reason.

You're running into this problem because the React.FC type was created long before React Server Components were added to React.

Instead they usually type functions as follows, relying on implicit return types:

```
type Props = { prop1: string, prop2: number }; 

export default async function Page({ prop1, prop2 }: Props) {
   //
}
```

Two things to note: 1) Your component's return type will be inferred. 2) You can use PropsWithChildren if you want it to type the special `children` prop for you.