# React, JS - function returning promise instead of actual object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I have the following function:

```
export const getUserData = async (userId) => {
    try {
        const app = getFirebaseApp();
        const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(app));
        const userRef = child(dbRef, `users/${userId}`);

        const snapshot = await get(userRef);
        return snapshot.val();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The function above should return an object containing data relating to a user.

Within one of my components, I attempt to call the function like so:

```
const ProtectedRoute =  ({children}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const userDataFunction = async (uid) => {
    return await getUserData(uid)
  }
  
  
  if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")) === null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")) === undefined) return <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  
  else {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"))
      const userData =  userDataFunction(data.userId)
      console.log(`user DATA: ${userData}`);
      dispatch(authenticate({token: data.token, userData}))
      return children
  }
}
```

The `userDataFunction` should return an object.

However, when using the `userData` variable, the value is equal to a promise object instead of the actual value. How do I ensure `userData` is always equal to the value of the promise, and not a promise object? Thanks.

Comment: All `async` functions return promises, that's how JS asynchronous code works. If `userDataFunction` is async, it will return a promise, even if you await the promise it receives from `getUserData`

Comment: Also, specifically for React, see this: [Using async/await inside a React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57847626/1218980)