# Error: Cannot destructure property 'devices' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following function in a page.txs file to grab a JSON response and use it in a page for Next 13 app

```
    const getDevices = async () => {
      try {
          const res = await fetch('/api/getdevice',{ cache: 'no-store' })
          if (!res.ok){
            throw new Error("Failed to get device list")
          }
          return res.json();
      } catch (error){
          console.log("Error loading devices: ", error);
      }
    }
```

In that same file I have my main page function which  calls the getDevices via an async call but I keep getting the error
**Error: Cannot destructure property 'devices' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.**

```
const HomePage = async () => {


   const {devices} = await getDevices();
   

  return (
    <>
 

    {devices.map((device)=> ...
```

Error Message

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'devices' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
    at HomePage (./app/home/page.tsx:46:13)
digest: "3194401674"
> 50 |    const {devices} = await getDevices();
     |          ^
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await inside a React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847626/using-async-await-inside-a-react-functional-component)

Comment: You cannot just mark a Component async and use await in it, you need to add a useState hook to hold the result of async fn call and a useEffect to execute this async function and to set state variable

Comment: @SergeySosunov you can in next

Comment: @Konrad Oh, my bad, saw react syntax and missed tags.. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If it is a server side component - the issue might be related to your `catch` block. If catch is executed - undefined is returned from your `getDevices` function and `const {devices} = await getDevices();` will fail with `TypeError` but Im not sure if that is the case and where does (intermediate value) comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the useEffect suggestion. To fix the issue I wrapped it in a use Effect function

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState();
 useEffect(() => {
    /* Load Devices */
    async function fetchDeviceData() {
      let deviceList = await getDevices();
      if (deviceList) {
```